# co and contravariant vectors, their difference and properties

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Very often when talking about covectors, co- and contravariant stuff, it's mentioned that there is no difference in "normal" linear algebra. That the difference only comes "when dealing with curved spaces" and some other exotic circumstances (like vector spaces without a scalar product). How is that so? As far as I know, covariant vectors are at the very least row vectors as opposed to column vectors. And they "can be understood" as functionals rather than vectors. And they transform differently, even in a simple orthonormal basis, or do they not?

Also I find the distinction between the basis vectors and the coordinate system very tricky. That's often rolled over in the explanations or blatantly ignored.

I've spend days on this subject now and gone through several books. How come that subject is so hard to teach? I doubt that it really is that difficult. And why are there so few examples which show a basis transformation, the different behavior of co- and contravariant vectors etc?

**edit**: Maybe to make a concrete example I took from "A Student’s Guide to Vectors and Tensors", p. 117:

[image]

He calculates the co- and contravariant components of this vector, which I could follow. But how does it even make sense to list the coordinates of the A vector as (7,2)? They're clearly based on the coordinate system and not the basis vectors.

Comment: These issues disappear if you don't **identify** things that are not equal. For instance, you might want to say that a vector $v$ is $\left(2,1\right)$ in coordinate system $A$ and is $\left(3,-1\right)$ in coordinate system $B$. This is confusing (it's an abuse of "is") and forces you to distinguish between vector transformations and coordinate transformations; I don't know about you, but I never got the hang of it. It is better to regard a coordinate system as just an isomorphism to your vector space from $\mathbb{k}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ (where $\mathbb{k}$ is your ground field) ...

Comment: ...; and then, instead of "$v$ is $(2,1)$ in coordinate system $A$" you can say "$v = A\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\\ 1 \end{array}\right)$" and things become clearer.

Comment: I think that the starting point is to distinguish between vectors (which transform as vectors) and coordinates (which are functions, and so transform differently from vectors). This is equivalent to talk about vector spaces $V$ and their duals $V^*$. Are you comfortable with this approach?

Comment: The idea that row vectors "can be understood" as functionals is essentially the following: If you write the elements of $\mathbb{k}^n$ as column vectors, then there is a correspondence between functionals on $\mathbb{k}^n$ (that is, $\mathbb{k}$-linear maps $\mathbb{k}^n \to \mathbb{k}$) and row vectors of length $n$. (The correspondence takes a functional $f$ to the row vector $\left(f\left(e_1\right), f\left(e_2\right), ..., f\left(e_n\right)\right)$.) This correspondence has the property that composition of a functional and a linear map ...

Comment: ... corresponds to multiplying the row vector (corresponding to the functional) with the matrix (corresponding to the map). If you would encode functionals as column vectors instead, this would not hold! (Instead you would have to work with transposes, which is nasty and confusing.)

Comment: @darij Is (2,1) being a row vector intended? I like the idea of viewing a coordinate system as a isomorphism, but it doesn't really help me with my issues

Comment: Uhm, you could just as well write a column vector there; I'm talking about notations I don't like :)

Comment: I don't understand your example :/

Comment: "with my issues": Well, it'd be clearer if you were more specific about what these are. The major confusion (to me) seems to come from the fact that one and the same vector can have two different sets of coordinates, and one set of coordinates can correspond to two different vectors, depending on the coordinate system. As soon as you stop viewing coordinate systems as identifications and view them as isomorphisms instead, this cannot create confusion anymore.

Comment: A basis is to my understanding and that of Wikipedia a thing that defines a coordinate system. So the basis vectors should always align with the axis of a coordinate system. In my edit-example, that is clearly not the case. Not just in the picture, in the calculations as well. He does some calculating with the basis vectors, but always goes back to the (7,2) coordinates of the A vector, which "implicitly" assume a e1=(1,0), e2=(0,1) basis although a different basis is explicitly written. That does not compute